# Gedit plugin for python autocomplete: how to install?

Tags: python, plugins, autocomplete, installation, gedit

Of course I tried to copy the files in the .gnome2/gedit/plugins and in the .local/share/gedit/plugins directories.
But it doesn't work at all. How do I install the plugin?

I'm on Fedora 18. Lxde desktop manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you have gedit3, have you checked that this is a plugin for gedit3, not gedit2?
Take a look at *.plugin file. It should say `IAge=3`.